# For loop does not end

Tags: c

Why I Can't Stop For Loop In This Program?

```
int main()
{
 unsigned char i;
 for(i=0;i<256;i++)
  {
   printf("%d\n",i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

*Why I Can't Stop For Loop In This Program?* Because variable `i` is declared as of `unsigned char` type which ranges from `0` to `255`, so here

```
for(i=0;i<256;i++) { } /* 0,1,2..255, 0, 1 */
```

`i` never reach `256` which results in infinite loop.

From [limits.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)

```
UCHAR_MAX   255
```